# Adding hosts to coredns

Tags: coredns

I have a kubernetes installation running coredns and I want to overwrite certain domains (or better subdomains) to resolve to an internal IP.

So reading this: https://coredns.io/plugins/hosts/, I updared my config (Corefile) to look like this:

```
.:53 {
    errors
    health {
       lameduck 5s
    }
    ready
    hosts {
        subdomain.my-domain.com 88.77.55.44
        fallthrough
    }
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
       pods insecure
       fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
       ttl 30
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
       max_concurrent 1000
    }
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}
```

But when I do:

```
dig subdomain.my-domain.com
```

I get the external IP of that domain, not `88.77.66.55`.

Something is wrong, but it's not clear to me what ...

Answer (score 4):

You need to use IP subdomain.domain.com like this:

```
...
    hosts {
        88.77.55.44 subdomain.my-domain.com
        fallthrough
    }
...
```

https://coredns.io/plugins/hosts/