# Is it possible to configure Openshift coreDNS with "host" statement like for vanilla Kubernetes?

Tags: openshift, coredns

I want to resolve a particular external test hostname to its IP on my Openshift (4.10.32) cluster. Please note that it's needed for some workloads deployed by operators so cannot (I think) update the deployments yaml that are generated by the operator to add hostAliases for example.

I tried to add host statement in my DNS config like others do on vanilla Kubernetes, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326757/adding-hosts-to-coredns) or [here](https://hjrocha.medium.com/add-a-custom-host-to-kubernetes-a06472cedccb).
In other word I'd like my coreDNS configmap (generated by the dns.operator/default) and which look like that:

```
oc get configmap/dns-default -n openshift-dns -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:5353 {
        bufsize 512
        errors
        log . {
            class error
        }
        health {
            lameduck 20s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus 127.0.0.1:9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
            policy sequential
        }
        cache 900 {
            denial 9984 30
        }
        reload
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-10-13T14:47:45Z"
  labels:
    dns.operator.openshift.io/owning-dns: default
  name: dns-default
  namespace: openshift-dns
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: operator.openshift.io/v1
    controller: true
    kind: DNS
    name: default
    uid: ef6eb600-c5ec-4cf5-a4f0-ca654b613e16
  resourceVersion: "2918009"
  uid: cf3cd62e-fef0-4c52-a7e0-6d8d8bf149ed
```

to be updated so that the coreDNS config part would look like this (considering I want to add a host hostname.my-domain that resolves to IP 1.2.3.4)

```
  Corefile: |
    .:5353 {
        bufsize 512
        errors
        log . {
            class error
        }
        health {
            lameduck 20s
        }
        ready
        hosts {
          1.2.3.4  hostname.my-domain
          fallthrough
        }
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus 127.0.0.1:9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
            policy sequential
        }
        cache 900 {
            denial 9984 30
        }
        reload
    }
```

Thx in advance for any hints on how to do that or on other ways to achieve what I'd like to do.

Comment: I think that would be possible by external DNS? Have you tried to config it?

Comment: yes indeed but I was looking if it could be possible to do it without using an external DNS....That was the whole point of my question